# Is it possible to refresh/reload script tag by click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Here is my code. I want to refresh/reload script tag and div content by a click.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<a id="refresh">click</a>

<script id="mydiv">
$("#mydiv").css( //some_css )
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function() {
     $("#mydiv").load("location.href + " .mydiv")
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: create a function and refresh that function on click.

Comment: and load that function at start ;)

Comment: Id be unique in html div and script have same id

Answer (score 5):

You can force the script to reload by adding a random variable after its URL.

```js
$("button").click( function(){
  var src = $(".reloadMe").attr('src');

  // Reload the script
  $(".reloadMe").attr('src', src.split('?')[0] + "?" + Math.floor(Math.random()* 10000000));
  
  // Reload the div
  $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " .mydiv")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="reloadMe" src="js/myScript.js"></script>
<button>Reload script</button>
```

This will produce :

```
src="js/myScript.js?61416981"
```

then

```
src="js/myScript.js?66541657"
```

then

```
src="js/myScript.js?14882875"
```

etc., forcing the browser to reload the script each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you do this without `src="js/myScript.js"` ? I need without `src`

Comment: Why do you _need_ inline script? It's considered as bad practice, you should keep your script in a separate file. I don't think it's possible to reload inline script anyway.